# How do capture lists of lambdas actually work in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I know that capture lists make variables available inside a lambda function body like so:

```
int pos(0);
std::function<void()> incPos = [&pos](){ ++pos; };
incPos(); //pos is now 1
```

But how does that capturing actually work on compiler level? Where are the captured addresses or captured values stored?

Comment: Lambdas are essentially [functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) that you don't have to write yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each lambda expression generates a unique function object (closure) that stores the captured variables as data members. For instance, the lambda expression in your code would be transformed into something like this by the compiler:

```
struct __uniquely_named_lambda
{
  __uniquely_named_lambda(int& pos)
  : pos(pos) {}
  int& pos;

  void operator()() const
  { ++pos; }
};
```

Invoking the lambda is simply a call to `operator()`.

The data member is a reference since you captured by reference. If you captured by value it would be a plain `int`. Also note that generated `operator()` is `const` by default. This is why you cannot modify captured variables unless you use the `mutable` keyword.

Comment: Note, however, that the above is **not** exactly what happens.  Unlike the magic `for` loop and like most of the rest of C++, it is the behavior that is standardized, and that behavior is not encoded in C++ code.  In particular, the above "fake" lambda has a constructor -- lambdas themselves need not have one (they can do it via magic).  In addition, if you pass the above "fake" lambda a reference, it remains valid so long as the referenced data is valid -- a real lambda technically requires both the data **and** the reference variable it captured remain valid.

Comment: @Yakk: Under the as-if rule, compilers have always had the freedom to implement C++ in any way the find appropriate as long as the _observable behavior_ is identical. The existence of constructors is not observable.

Comment: @msalters Use type deduction then traits classes.  A few of them differ based on constructor existence.  Non-explicit unary ctors can be detected (even if private) via function overloads (again, type via type deduction), but not certain if I can do the same with explicit or multi arg (thinkimg `{}` construction with overloads?) -- I am unconvinced it is not observable, but not certain.