# What does the word capture mean in the context of lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Can somebody please provide some insights on this? Is the lambda capturing external variables, or is the outside world capturing values produced by the lambdas? What does it mean for a certain variable to be captured?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *or is the outside world capturing values produced by the lambdas*, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23499673/241631) answers your question.

Comment: It literally means to copy objects, (or references to objects) into the scope of the function. The function literally *captures* part of the environment from which it was created. This gives it context data to operate with.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The lambda is capturing an outside variable.

A lambda is a syntax for creating a class. Capturing a variable means that variable is passed to the constructor for that class.

A lambda can specify whether it's passed by reference or by value. For example:

```
[&] { x += 1; }       // capture by reference
[=] { return x + 1; } // capture by value
```

The first produces a class roughly like this:

```
class foo { 
    int &x;
public:
    foo(int &x) : x(x) {}
    void operator()() const { x += 1; }
};
```

The second produces a class something like this:

```
class bar {
    int x;
public:
    bar(int x) : x(x) {}
    int operator()() const { return x + 1; }
};
```

As with most uses of references, capturing by reference can create a dangling reference if the closure (the object of the class created by the lambda expression) out-lives the object that was captured.

Comment: "A lambda is a syntax for creating a class." Not necessarily.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Oh? What are the alternatives?

Comment: `[](){/* ... body ... */}` is convertible to a plain function pointer `void(*)()`, so could be implemented as a free-standing function. Anyway, the compiler could do all sorts of trickery for capturing-lambdas. It could define functions that take pointers to local variables and dereference them for capture. It could simply append `int x = /* captured value */` to the lambdas body in some cases. There are many ways it could be implemented other than a class with `operator()()`. It's really up to the implementation.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Hmm...the standard seems to disagree (§5.1.2/3): "The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a **unique, unnamed nonunion class type** — called the closure type — whose properties are described below." It's certainly true that the usual "as if" rule applies to the implementation of that class, but they don't make it any less a class.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Yeah, it's a class with a conversion operator to function pointer

Answer (score 11):

Jerry Coffin gave you detailed response,I agree that lambda is syntax for creating a class.There are bunch of options about the way variables are captured and how.List of options:

```
[]  Capture nothing (or, a scorched earth strategy?)
[&] Capture any referenced variable by reference
[=] Capture any referenced variable by making a copy
[=, &foo]   Capture any referenced variable by making a copy, but capture variable foo by reference
[bar]   Capture bar by making a copy; don't copy anything else
[this]  Capture the this pointer of the enclosing class
```

Answer (score 3):

Lambda captures variables which it otherwise will not have access to. One can specify how A lambda should capture a variable .i.e value,reference .
This has been explained really well here 
[In lambda functions syntax, what purpose does a 'capture list' serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554102/in-lambda-functions-syntax-what-purpose-does-a-capture-list-serve)