# Fix "lambda has no capture-default"

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm using lambdas for the first time and having a problem which I can't figure out.

I'm getting multiple errors:

```
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:7:19: error: 'x' is not captured
    7 |         int sum = x + y;
      |                   ^
<source>:6:20: note: the lambda has no capture-default
    6 |     auto lambda = []() {
      |                    ^
<source>:4:9: note: 'int x' declared here
    4 |     int x = 5, y = 10;
      |         ^
<source>:7:23: error: 'y' is not captured
    7 |         int sum = x + y;
      |                       ^
<source>:6:20: note: the lambda has no capture-default
    6 |     auto lambda = []() {
      |                    ^
<source>:4:16: note: 'int y' declared here
    4 |     int x = 5, y = 10;
      |
```

My code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 5, y = 10;

    auto lambda = []() {
        int sum = x + y;
        std::cout << "Sum of x and y is: " << sum << std::endl;
    };

    lambda();
}
```

It says my variables are declared, but why are they not found?

Comment: Kindly do proper research before asking any question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to "search and then research" and you'll find many related SO posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables are not in the scope of the lambda because they are not captured or pass as arguments as seen in the error:

```
<source>:6:20: note: the lambda has no capture-default
    6 |     auto lambda = []() {
      |
```

You could either capture the variables (there are multiple possibilities to do this -> see the references below)

```cpp
auto lambda = [&]() {
...
};
```

or pass them as arguments

```cpp
auto lambda = [](auto x, auto y) {
...
};
```

I would recommend reading ["What does the word capture mean in the context of lambdas?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979303/what-does-the-word-capture-mean-in-the-context-of-lambdas), [cppreference.com - Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) or [Lambda expressions in C++ - Capture clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-170#capture-clause) for more information about the different approaches.

Answer (score 4):

You need to *capture* the variables, so they become part of the lambdas closure (its scope):

```
auto lambda = [x, y]() {
    int sum = x + y;
    std::cout << "Sum of x and y is: " << sum << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: Why call the closure object the lambda’s “scope”?